# Open file browser via xdg from html link

Tags: linux, xdgutils

Is it possible to open a file browser via `xdg`/`xdg-open` by clicking on a HTML link?

E.g.:

I'd like to open my file browser (Thunar / XFCE / Xubuntu 18.04) by clicking on a link like: `xdg:///media/Data/`.
If I enter the URL manually a xdg dialog which asks whether I want to open `xdg-open` shows. But if I click `Ok` then an error shows that the address could not be found/opened. The path to the directory, however, is correct and exists.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question...

I can open the file manager with `xdg-open` from the terminal by running:

```bash
xdg-open file:///home
```

or

```bash
xdg-open /home
```

In my case `nautilus` opens up and shows me that path.

With a web-browser it is possible to do the same by browsing an `html` file containing this lines:

```html
<a href="file:///home">file:///home</a>

<br>

<a href="/home">/home</a>
```

Both links are managed by the browser, in my case (using Brave browser) I end up browsing those paths though my browser.

I think that what you need is opening those links directly with the file-explorer (Thunar in your case), and not with the web-browser built-in file browser.

I guess this is possible by using more complex `html` (or `js` or `php`) code. Or even by setting up the browser so that it always opens `file://` paths using the OS file manager (maybe there are already extensions to achieve that).

I would be cool to have something like `xdg-open filebrowser:///home`, but I am not sure that something like this exists...